# + operator overload to add different C++ class object

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have seen many example to add objects of same class.I was trying to add two different class objects using operator overloading.
Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class B;
class A
{
public:
int x;
A(int t=99)
{
x=t;
}
friend const A operator+( A& m, B& n);
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& c);
};

const A operator+(A& c1,B& c2) 
{
     A temp;
     temp.x = c1.x + c2.y; 
         return temp;
 }
 ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const A& c)
 { 
    os << c.x;
    return os;
}


class B
{
public:
int y;
B(int e=90)
{
y=e;
}
friend const A operator+( A& m, B& n);
};

int main()
{
A a,u;
B b;
u=a+b;
cout<<"Value of A+B"<<u;
return 0;
}
```

When i compiled my code it shows Error:

**$ g++ operator_overloading.cpp**

**operator_overloading.cpp: In function ‘const A operator+(A&, B&)’:**

**operator_overloading.cpp:19:21: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct B’**

**operator_overloading.cpp:3:7: error: forward declaration of ‘struct B’**

What i have done wrong??

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the operator after the definition of class B.
For example

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class B;
class A
{
public:
int x;
A(int t=99)
{
x=t;
}
friend const A operator+( const A& m, const B& n);
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& c);
};

 ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const A& c)
 { 
    os << c.x;
    return os;
}


class B
{
public:
int y;
B(int e=90)
{
y=e;
}
friend const A operator+( const A& m, const B& n);
};

const A operator+(const A& c1, const B& c2) 
{
     A temp;
     temp.x = c1.x + c2.y; 
         return temp;
 }

 //...
```

Otherwise the compiler does not know what data members class B has.
Also it is better to define paraneters of the operator as constant references. In this case the operator can deal with temporary objects.

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear. You have attempted to use members of `B` using only a forward declaration.

Comment: I have always thought that "error: forward declaration of ..." was a strangely named error message. I remember that when I had started learning C++, it gave me the impression that the forward declaration itself somehow was an error. I can understand how this might confuse people.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: That's not an error message. It's the second line of the error message that starts "invalid use of ..." and is simply telling you, for information, more context for the error. It's been broken out onto its own line so that the filename and line number can be reported in the conventional way. Granted, GCC renders it in a way that kinda makes it look like a second error message, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is caused by the fact that you've defined your `const A operator+(A& c1,B& c2)` before defining the class B.

At this moment B is hence still an incomplete type (meaning you can only use pointers and references to it, but nothing else).

Just move this definition after you've defined B.

Answer (score 0):

The line `class B;` forward-declares `B`. This tells the compiler that a class called "B" exists, but nothing else. When you attempt to use `c2.y`, where `c2` is a `B`, the compiler does not yet know that `B` even has a `y` member.

One solution in this case is to move the definition of `B` so that it appears before the `operator+` definition:

```
class B;
class A
{
public:
int x;
A(int t=99)
{
x=t;
}
friend const A operator+( A& m, B& n);
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& c);
};

class B
{
public:
int y;
B(int e=90)
{
y=e;
}
friend const A operator+( A& m, B& n);
};

const A operator+(A& c1,B& c2) 
{
     A temp;
     temp.x = c1.x + c2.y; 
         return temp;
 }
```