# Overloading += in c++ to add one object into another

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I have class Human, and a class List.How to overload operator +=, so i can do:
  list+=human
in that way i add one object of Human class to my list.

Thank you.

Comment: please post some code that you tried.

Comment: I’d recommend *not* even implementing a list structure: instead just use `std::list<Human>`. That assumes you actually need a list to start with. The default container should be `std::vector<Human>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either declare the operator as a member function of the class `List` like

```
class List
{
public:
    List & operator +=( const Human &human )
    {
        // something like
        // push_back( human );

        return *this;
    }
//…
};
```

Or define it as a non class function like

```
List & operator +=( List &list, const Human &human )
{

    // something like
    // push_back( human );

    return list;
}
```

If the implementation of the operator requires to access non-public data members of the class `List` then the function should be a friend function of the class as for example

```
class List
{
public:
    friend List & operator +=( List &, const Human & );
//…
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this you can define the operator on namespace level:

```
list& operator+=(list& lhs, human const& rhs)
{
    lhs.add(rhs);  // actually add human to the list
    return lhs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197977/operator-overload-to-add-different-c-class-object) as a reference, you can define both of your classes and then define the "add" overloading operator of List Class later.